# Center Label With bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this code :

```html
<div class="col-md-3 form-group">
  <label>Ville de chargement</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control collectes-ville text-center" name="villeChargement" placeholder="Chargement">
  <label>Ville de livraison</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control collectes-ville text-center" name="villeLivraison" placeholder="Livraison" value="">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 form-group">
  <label>Chargement mini</label>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control collectes-date-chargement-min text-center" name="DebutChargement" placeholder="Date début chargement" value="">
  <label>
    <->
  </label>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker2" class="form-control collectes-date-chargement-min text-center" name="FinChargement" placeholder="Date fin chargement" value="">
</div>
</div>
```

And it gives

[image]

I would like to center the labels too... I tried class="text-center" but it didn't work. Could someone help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add `text-align: center` in your CSS or `text-center` class to your parent element (probably to a `row` or `container`).

### **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/RoBRyz)**

Comment: Why not use Bootstraps `text-centre` class? That's what it's there for.

Comment: Very good, thank you. I'm just a begginner. I tried to use text-center in <label> but, it was in fact in the parent element : container that i had to put it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Beware that this will make everything else inside your `container` centre aligned text, unless you specifically state otherwise.

Comment: for lable with `input-group-text` class it didnt work. Then I wraped lable's text by `<text>` tag and put in it  `w-100`. Now I have nice looking form label with its centered text. Talking about **Bootstrap 5** .

Comment: Doesn't work in Bootstrap 5 and floating labels. Anyone got any ideas for this?

Comment: @YaddyVirus Try `width: 100%; text-align: center; transform-origin: center;` on the label.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :D

http://jsfiddle.net/ndfxgvow/

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6 ">
        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
              <label>Ville de chargement</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control collectes-ville text-center" name="villeChargement" placeholder="Chargement">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
              <label>Ville de livraison</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control collectes-ville text-center" name="villeLivraison" placeholder="Livraison" value="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
          <label>Chargement mini</label>
          <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control collectes-date-chargement-min text-center" name="DebutChargement" placeholder="Date dĆ©but chargement" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
          <label><-></label>
          <input type="text" id="datepicker2" class="form-control collectes-date-chargement-min text-center" name="FinChargement" placeholder="Date fin chargement" value=""> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```